# Laravel 5.2 Create query using url get parameters to select fields, match string and sort

Tags: php, laravel

I have seen some API have simple query that can be constructed in url. For example, I have products table with Product model.

products table properties:

- id
- product_name
- barcode
- category_id
- description
- price

How can I do query in url as below (fields parameter means to select those specified fields):

`http://example.com/product?fields=id,product_name,price,barcode&sortby=price`

or maybe like this to get price equalto 10.00:

`http://example.com/product?fields=id,product_name,price,barcode&price=10.00`

I know in laravel we can check the get parameters using `$request->has()` and get the value using `$request->input('fieldname)` to check and retrieve the value one by one

But I think there should be a better way to do that or maybe there is a wrapper function that can be used for all controllers to read the query from url get parameters.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, here we go. I'll try to be didactic.

**TO DO**

*Build an API that search and returns products from database based on URL parameters.*

**Properties**

First of all, we set an array with our all valid properties.

```
$props = [
  'id',
  'product_name',
  'barcode',
  'category_id',
  'description',
  'price'
];
```

**Parameters**

Let's store all parameters that comes from URL in a variable:

```
$parameters = Input::all();
```

**Without parameters**

If any parameters was passed, we can select all products with their fields and return the result:

```
if (empty($parameters)) {
  $products = Product::all();
  return $products;
}
```

---

**Organizing things**

Let's consider that we have 3 "categories" of parameters:

1. That determines the fields to be selected (optional).
2. That determines the result order (optional).
3. That determines the search clauses (optional).

---

**Identifying the fields**

For the first category, we'll use the `fields` parameter that receives a string separating each field by commas.

```
$fieldsParam = $parameters['fields']; // Gets fields string.
$fieldsParamSplit = explode(',', $fieldsParam); // Split the fields string into array.
$fields = array_intersect($props, $fieldsParamSplit); // Gets only wanted fields.
```

---

**The order**

For the second category, we'll use the `sortby` parameter that receives a specific field (property) name.

```
$orderProp = null;

// Check if parameter "sortby" exists and if it is valid.
if (isset($parameters['sortby']) && in_array($parameters['sortby'], $props)) {
  $orderProp = $parameters['sortby'];
}
```

---

**There's some clause?**

For the third category, we'll use all parameters (except those mentioned above) to build the *where clauses* of search.

```
$clauses = []; 

foreach ($props as $prop) {

  // Check if the current property is present in parameters.       
  if (in_array($prop, array_keys($parameters))) {
    // Each item represents a where clause.
    $clauses[$prop] = $parameters[$prop];
  }
}
```

**Building the collection**

Now that all the paremeters are validated, we can build the collection of products and return the result.

```
if ($orderProp) {
  $products = Product::where($clauses)->orderBy($orderProp)->get($fields);
} else {
  $products = Product::where($clauses)->get($fields);       
}
return $products;
```

Comment: Very nice sir. You also added validation part for the `fields` using `array_intersect`. Never thought that. I works except for last code there need to change `if ($orderProp)` i assume. Thanks sir

Comment: @h44f33z oh yeah, sure

Comment: this line also need to change to use `array_keys` in `// Check if the current property is present in parameters.`        
  `if (in_array($prop, array_keys($parameters)))`. Thats it. now i want to put at base controller so it can be reuse. Thanks